# Issue on fast execution of test suite in selenium ide

Tags: selenium-ide

The scenario is,

- Click on a icon | which opens a popup;
- Select a button from popup | where the selected buttons name to be loaded to a datatable;

Here, while running test suite fast, the particular popup opens, but the button is not getting selected.

But when running it in slow mode or executing textcase separately , it works fine.

i tried `clickandwait`, `assert` , etc., but i'm missing something important.

Is there any way to make it work while running it in fast mode?

This is the code,

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=btnPButton</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=FCode7</td> //This is the button id inside the popup.
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=RGrade</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=btnCC</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=btn12029</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=btn12039</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=HomeTeam</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=HJNo36</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=PlayerPosition</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=PlayerPosition45</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=btn12016</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=btn12004</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to fix this:

1. Do a waitForElementPresent on the button, then select it. That's usually the best way I've found to fix issues with elements not being displayed fast enough on the page.
2. You can set the speed during the test.  Use setSpeed to set the speed fast during those sections of the test where fast works fine, if you run into a section where you need to slow it down, use setSpeed again.

Okay, here's what I would do, and have had success using this method:

```
click | id=btnPButton |
waitForElementPresent | id=FCode7 |
click | id=FCode7
```

You may want to add a pause after that to make sure it clicks before continuing the rest of the test.

Comment: It is working when i run it slow, because i'm getting the response from ajax, but while running it fast before getting the response it moving on to the next testcase. as you told `waitForElementPresent` is also not helping. Is there any alternative?

Comment: i have updated the source of the selenium code in the question.

Comment: So I I read this correctly, clcking on id=FCode7 opens the popup, then the next instruction is to click on id=RGrade which is on the popup?

Comment: Sorry `id=FCode7` is the button id. On clicking `id=btnPButton` popup opens.

Comment: Thanks, This solution made me reduce the execution time, though it couldn't exe to the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Try waitforvisible (Xpath of the button) it will work

Comment: Tried, but same result. And about the Xpath it will automatically detect the Xpath while selecting the button itself, so button will be visible, but On button click, it will take time for ajax to respond, in the meantime other test cases being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i know this thread is old but I used waitForElementPresent and then put a pause and it has worked fine for me on fast